# Postgres: Reference Cell of the other table

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a tables here

Table 1

```
id  value
1   30
2   40
3   34
4   56
```

and I would like to create a "reference cell" on Table 2

Table 2 (Collect the MAX from Table 1)

```
Name  value
1&2   40 [MAX Table1 (1,2)]
3&4   56 [MAX Table1 (3,4)]
```

How could I achieve the reference table. Which Table 2 references content in Table 1. Whenever table 1 is being updated, the value on Table 2 will be updated as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The straight forward way is to implement a trigger firing on write of table 1. You can read about that type of trigger [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will go and research the trigger method

Comment: Why are you grouping id 1 and 2? Is there a logic behind?

Answer (score 1):

The trigger way can be done like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_table1
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON table1
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_trigger_table1();
```

and the function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_trigger_table1()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
BEGIN
IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') OR (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
    IF NEW.id=1 OR NEW.id=2 THEN
        IF NEW.value>(SELECT MAX(value) FROM table1 WHERE (id=1 or id=2)) then
            UPDATE table2 SET value=NEW.value WHERE name='1&2';
        end if;
    ELSE IF NEW.id=3 OR NEW.id=4 THEN
        IF NEW.value>(SELECT MAX(value) FROM table1 WHERE (id=3 or id=4)) THEN
            UPDATE table2 SET value=NEW.value WHERE name='3&4';
        END IF; 
    END IF;
END IF; 

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Views can do this job too, if you want i'll show you a sample.